# How to use CURL response in Kubernates CRON Jobs

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, curl, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

We have a set of spring boot applications deployed in the Kubernetes cluster. For a few of them, we have designed the corn jobs which get triggered at the required frequency which is working fine in which we do hit our specific internal API that has been developed. The requirement is to generate a token using the API and pass the generated token as authentication. To do the same I am thinking of hitting the API using curl but not sure how I can use the response from curl and use that token to pass as an Authorization header in the subsequent curl request. Along with token, I do also need to send API Keys that we have but I am searching for a way to store it in an encrypted way and decode it in cron job before making an API hit.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: api-cron
spec:
  # At 08:00 on Tuesday
  schedule: "0 08 * * 2"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          restartPolicy: Never
          containers:
            - command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
              env:
              - name: POD_NAMESPACE
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: metadata.namespace
              args:
                - |    
                  curl -s -i \
                  -X POST "http://application.$POD_NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local/endpoint" \
                  -d ""
              name: curl
              image: curlimages/curl:7.80.0
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this. If yes, kindly shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Write a shell script and run it as container CMD or entrypoint. include the logic in the shell script.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. Can you please share any example or link for the same if possible